# RabbitMQ: How to set common prefetchCount for all consumers?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue

I need to define the number of simultaneously processing messages for a queue. The prefetchCount works fine, but the limitation is for each consumer. In my case, I can have multiple consumers, but I need a common limit (e.g. 2 consumers, limit set to 5. If the first consumer is processing 3 messages, the second can take only 2).

Do you have any idea how can I achieve​ it?

Background:

- Springboot application.
- Each consumer is an instance of spring microservice.
- Messages are added to named queue by other microservice.
- Each consumer will process messages from many named queues.
- Each named queues should have separate limit of simultaneously processing messages,

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: Each queue is related to the business case. It contains calls to make. Each business case has certain resources (number of agents for calling). The limit I want to set is the number of simultaneous calls. e.g. I can have 4 consumer instances and 20 queues. Each queue has a specified number of agents for making calls. Each consumer (microservice instance) can process calls from all queues, but the agents limit must be respected.

Answer (score 0):

You should define sum concurrency of all rabbit listeners to be equal to the number of  your agents. I.e. - number of available agent is 6, then if you have 2 consumers (rabbit listeners), each one will have concurrency as 3 (core and max)

Comment: I thought about this solution but it requires knowledge about consumer instances. The application will be deployed in Kubernetes cluster and consumer instances will be added dynamically.

Comment: If you want to throttle the number of concurrently processed messages you have to know the number of available agents.... Regardless the solution you implement.

Comment: BTW, if your agents login when they start working then you can know the number... Distributed lock is your friend